# minimize rows based on data in table

Tags: sql

i have one table in that few rows are there ex:student table

```
Id name registeredDate feescollectiondate
1  AAA  01-jun-2019     NULL
2  BBB  02-Jun-2019     NULL
3  CCC  02-Jun-2019     NULL
4  AAA  NULL            02-jun-2019
5  BBB  NULL            02-Jun-2019
6  AAA  NULL            01-JULY-2019
7  CCC  NULL            01-JULY-2019
8  BBB  NULL            01-AUG-2019
9  DDD  04-AUG-2019     NULL
```

now i want to select data from this student table only for june moth either student registered in june month or paid fees in june month.

i have written query using CTE and union but to i am not getting expected results.

```
select * 
from (
  select distinct * 
  from student 
  where org_id=14 
    and unit_id=10054 
    and registeredDate between '01/01/2018 00:00:00' and '01/31/2018 23:59:59'
) a
  full join (
    select distinct *  
    from student 
    where org_id=14 
      and unit_id=10054 
      and feescollectiondate between '06/01/2019 00:00:00' and '06/30/2019 23:59:59' ) b
on a.name =b.name
```

one more method i used

```
;with cte as(
   select distinct Id
         ,name
         ,registeredDate
         ,feescollectiondate from student where registeredDate between '06/01/2019 00:00:00' and '06/30/2019 23:59:59'
),cte2 as (
  select distinct Id
         ,name
         ,registeredDate
         ,feescollectiondate 
  from student 
  where Id=14 
    and unit_id=10054 
    and feescollectiondate between '06/01/2019 00:00:00' and '06/30/2019 23:59:59' 
)
select coalesce(t1.Id,t2.Id) as Id
      ,coalesce(t1.name,t2.name) as name
      ,coalesce(t1.registeredDate,t2.registeredDate) as registeredDate
      ,coalesce(t1.feescollectiondate,t2.feescollectiondate) as  feescollectiondate 
from cte t1 
  full outer join cte2 t2 on t1.name=t2.name 
order by t1.name
```

what result i am getting is

```
1  AAA  01-jun-2019     NULL
2  BBB  02-Jun-2019     NULL
3  CCC  02-Jun-2019     NULL
4  AAA  NULL            02-jun-2019
5  BBB  NULL            02-Jun-2019
```

But what result i want is:

```
1  AAA  01-jun-2019     02-jun-2019
2  BBB  02-Jun-2019     02-Jun-2019
3  CCC  02-Jun-2019     NULL
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `select distinct * ` never makes sense because the `*` includes the primary key and thus the `distinct` will not remove any rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
;with cte as(
   select distinct Id
         ,name
         ,registeredDate
         ,feescollectiondate from student where registeredDate between '06/01/2019 00:00:00' and '06/30/2019 23:59:59'
),cte2 as (
  select distinct Id
         ,name
         ,registeredDate
         ,feescollectiondate 
  from student 
  where Id=14 
    and unit_id=10054 
    and feescollectiondate between '06/01/2019 00:00:00' and '06/30/2019 23:59:59' 
)
select coalesce(t1.Id,t2.Id) as Id
      ,coalesce(t1.name,t2.name) as name
      ,max(coalesce(t1.registeredDate,t2.registeredDate)) as registeredDate
      ,max(coalesce(t1.feescollectiondate,t2.feescollectiondate)) as  feescollectiondate 
from cte t1 
  full outer join cte2 t2 on t1.name=t2.name 
group by coalesce(t1.Id,t2.Id),coalesce(t1.name,t2.name)
```